# Hiding Legend for Zero Value Chart Items javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to the forums, so I hope I'm not asking a question that has been answered in the past. I've tried to be thorough looking for answer before posting.

I am currently working on a pie chart that will eventually be used for tracking financial expenses. Right now I have several categories that make up each slice. I am trying to hide the legend for the zero value slices.

I am doing this in javaFX. I'm still very green when it comes to programming and don't have experience outside of Java. Any help as explained to dummies would be appreciated. Thanks.

Added a picture and complete code to illustrate the problem at hand. Restaurants & Dining, and Shopping & entertainment both have zero values. I want to hide the legend for those items in this example.

```
package Example;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;

public class PieExampleController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private PieChart pieChart;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data("Groceries", 1),
            new PieChart.Data("Transportation", 1),
            new PieChart.Data("Restaurants & Dining", 0),
            new PieChart.Data("Shopping & Entertainment", 0));

        pieChart.setData(pieChartData);

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Advice no 1 - Always try to submit a code in their complete form. If possible, try to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated the code with a simpler example and provided a screen shot of the legend, and what I am trying to remove.

Comment: You could check if the value is zero before adding them to the ObservableList

Comment: pieChartData.removeIf(data -> data.getPieValue() == 0);

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i do it:

```
    List<PieChart.Data> dataArrayList = new LinkedList<Data>();
    if (value1>0) {
            Data data = new PieChart.Data("my label", value1);
            dataArrayList.add(data);
    }
     ...

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding only not empty data entries (or removing empty entries) manually once at startup is just fine if the data is immutable and unmodifiable. On the other hand, if it can change during the lifetime of the chart, we need a mechanism that handles the add/remove automagically: FilteredList to the rescue.

Below is an example that

- configures a source list with an extractor (on the pieValueProperty): doing so will notify any listChangeListener on change of that value with a change of type update
- wraps a FilteredList around the source list
- configures the pieChart with the filteredList

With that in place, we can install a predicate on the filteredList that hides items as needed: the example uses a Slider to update the lower threshhold of which data values should be included in the chart.

Unfortunately, PieChart has a [couple of bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198823) (sigh... whatever I touch in FX, they always boil up ...) that interfere with such a simple setup

- due to a freaky mixture of node/value plus "optimized" internal data structure plus incorrect implementation of syncing the internal (linked) data structure with changes to the list the chart can't be animated
- the sync can't handle changes of type replaced at all (which is what FilteredList fires on resetting the predicate)

In an example both issues can be avoided by disabling animation and clearing out the list (set a predicate that blocks all) before setting the real condition. In producation code such tweaking may or may not be possible.

The example:

```
public class FilteredPieChartExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        FilteredList<Data> filtered = getChartData();
        //ListChangeReport report = new ListChangeReport(filtered);

        PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(filtered);
        // bug in pieChart: can't handle data modification with animation on
        pieChart.setAnimated(false);

        // use slider to set lower threshhold for value of data to show in pie
        Slider slider =  new Slider(-1., 100., -1.);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
            // actually, cannot handle data modification at all ... need to clear out first ...
            // bug in pieChart.dataChangeListener: doesn't handle replaced correctly
            filtered.setPredicate(data -> false);
            filtered.setPredicate(data -> data.getPieValue() > nv.doubleValue());
            //report.prettyPrint();
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("PieChart");
        Pane root = new VBox(pieChart, slider); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private FilteredList<Data> getChartData() {
        // use ObservableList with extractor on pieValueProperty
        ObservableList<Data> answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                e -> new Observable[] {e.pieValueProperty()}
                );
        answer.addAll(
                new Data("java", 17.56), 
                new Data("C", 17.06), 
                new Data("C++", 8.25), 
                new Data("C#", 8.20), 
                new Data("ObjectiveC", 6.8), 
                new Data("PHP", 6.0), 
                new Data("(Visual)Basic", 4.76),
                new Data("Other", 31.37),
                new Data("empty", 0)
                );
        return new FilteredList<>(answer);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FilteredPieChartExample.class
            .getName());

}
```